# How to show contextMenu just on records of a listGrid?

Tags: contextmenu, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm using smartGwt 3.0, I have a `listGrid` with some records that i want to show `contextMenu` when a record is clicked. I'v written the codes for that and everything works fine.

My problem is that when I right click on my listGrid (**not on a record**) the context menu appears that I dont want this to happen. then what should I do to solve this problem?

```
listGrid.addCellContextClickHandler(new CellContextClickHandler() {
            public void onCellContextClick(final CellContextClickEvent rightClickEvent) 
            {                                                   
                Menu menu = new Menu();             
                MenuItem hangupItem = new MenuItem("Hangup Call", "agent/hangup.png");              
                hangupItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {             
                    public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) 
                    {
                        SC.confirm("Are you sure ? ", new BooleanCallback() {
                            public void execute(Boolean value) {
                                if (value != null && value) {   
                                    labelAnswer.setContents("OK...");   
                                } else {   
                                    labelAnswer.setContents("Cancel...");   
                                }   
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                menu.addItem(hangupItem);
                listGrid.setContextMenu(menu);              
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

add this listener to your listgrid

```
listgrid.addShowContextMenuHandler(new ShowContextMenuHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onShowContextMenu(ShowContextMenuEvent event) {         
        event.cancel();
    }
});
```